# How to fill NA by taking mean of two columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Below is the `dput` of my dataset. I am trying to fill my dataset such that if there is `NA` present in particular column of the year, then the `NA` should be filled with `mean` of other two years. For example, in the dataset below, Congo contains `NA` for the "Economy.2015" column, so that `NA` should be filled with mean from the columns "Economy.2016" and "Economy.2017".

**dput**

```
structure(list(Country = c("Angola", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Congo (Kinshasa)", "Greece", "Indonesia", "Iraq", "Sierra Leone", 
"Sudan", "Togo"), Region = c("Sub-Saharan Africa", "Central and Eastern Europe", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Western Europe", "Southeastern Asia", 
"Middle East and Northern Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa"), Happiness.Rank.2015 = c(137L, 96L, 120L, 
102L, 74L, 112L, 123L, 118L, 158L), Happiness.Score.2015 = c(4.033, 
4.949, 4.517, 4.857, 5.399, 4.677, 4.507, 4.55, 2.839), Standard.Error.2015 = c(0.04758, 
0.06913, 0.0368, 0.05062, 0.02596, 0.05232, 0.07068, 0.0674, 
0.06727), Economy.2015 = c(0.75778, 0.83223, NA, 1.15406, 0.82827, 
0.98549, 0.33024, 0.52107, 0.20868), Family.2015 = c(0.8604, 
0.91916, 1.0012, 0.92933, 1.08708, 0.81889, 0.95571, 1.01404, 
0.13995), Health.2015 = c(0.16683, 0.79081, 0.09806, 0.88213, 
0.63793, 0.60237, NA, 0.36878, 0.28443), Freedom.2015 = c(0.10384, 
0.09245, 0.22605, 0.07699, 0.46611, NA, 0.4084, 0.10081, 0.36453
), Trust.2015 = c(0.07122, 0.00227, 0.07625, 0.01397, NA, 0.13788, 
0.08786, 0.1466, 0.10731), Generosity.2015 = c(0.12344, 0.24808, 
0.24834, NA, 0.51535, 0.17922, 0.21488, 0.19062, 0.16681), Dystopia.Residual.2015 = c(1.94939, 
2.06367, 2.86712, 1.80101, 1.86399, 1.95335, 2.51009, 2.20857, 
1.56726), Region.2016 = c("Sub-Saharan Africa", "Central and Eastern Europe", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Western Europe", "Southeastern Asia", 
"Middle East and Northern Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa"), Happiness.Rank.2016 = c(141L, 87L, 125L, 
99L, 79L, 112L, 111L, 133L, 155L), Happiness.Score.2016 = c(3.866, 
5.163, 4.272, 5.033, 5.314, 4.575, 4.635, 4.139, 3.303), Lower.CI.2016 = c(3.753, 
5.063, 4.191, 4.935, 5.237, 4.446, 4.505, 3.928, 3.192), Upper.CI.2016 = c(3.979, 
5.263, 4.353, 5.131, 5.391, 4.704, 4.765, 4.35, 3.414), Economy.2016 = c(0.84731, 
0.93383, 0.05661, 1.24886, 0.95104, 1.07474, 0.36485, 0.63069, 
0.28123), Family.2016 = c(0.66366, 0.64367, 0.80676, 0.75473, 
0.87625, 0.59205, 0.628, 0.81928, NA), Health.2016 = c(0.04991, 
0.70766, 0.188, 0.80029, 0.49374, 0.51076, NA, 0.29759, 0.24811
), Freedom.2016 = c(0.00589, 0.09511, 0.15602, 0.05822, 0.39237, 
0.24856, 0.30685, NA, 0.34678), Trust.2016 = c(0.08434, NA, 0.06075, 
0.04127, 0.00322, 0.13636, 0.08196, 0.10039, 0.11587), Generosity.2016 = c(0.12071, 
0.29889, 0.25458, NA, 0.56521, 0.19589, 0.23897, 0.18077, 0.17517
), Dystopia.Residual.2016 = c(2.09459, 2.48406, 2.74924, 2.12944, 
2.03171, 1.81657, 3.01402, 2.10995, 2.1354), Happiness.Rank.2017 = c(140L, 
90L, 126L, 87L, 81L, 117L, 106L, 130L, 150L), Happiness.Score.2017 = c(3.79500007629395, 
5.18200016021729, 4.28000020980835, 5.22700023651123, 5.26200008392334, 
4.49700021743774, 4.70900011062622, 4.13899993896484, 3.49499988555908
), Whisker.high.2017 = c(3.95164193540812, 5.27633568674326, 
4.35781083270907, 5.3252461694181, 5.35288859814405, 4.62259140968323, 
4.85064333498478, 4.34574716508389, 3.59403811171651), whisker.low.2017 = c(3.63835821717978, 
5.08766463369131, 4.20218958690763, 5.12875430360436, 5.17111156970263, 
4.37140902519226, 4.56735688626766, 3.9322527128458, 3.39596165940166
), Economy.2017 = c(0.858428180217743, 0.982409417629242, 0.0921023488044739, 
1.28948748111725, 0.995538592338562, 1.10271048545837, 0.36842092871666, 
0.65951669216156, 0.305444717407227), Family.2017 = c(1.10441195964813, 
1.0693359375, 1.22902345657349, 1.23941457271576, 1.27444469928741, 
0.978613197803497, 0.984136044979095, 1.21400856971741, 0.431882530450821
), Health.2017 = c(0.0498686656355858, 0.705186307430267, 0.191407024860382, 
0.810198903083801, 0.492345720529556, 0.501180469989777, 0.00556475389748812, 
0.290920823812485, 0.247105568647385), Freedom.2017 = c(NA, 0.204403176903725, 
0.235961347818375, 0.0957312509417534, 0.443323463201523, 0.288555532693863, 
0.318697690963745, 0.0149958552792668, 0.38042613863945), Generosity.2017 = c(0.097926490008831, 
0.328867495059967, 0.246455833315849, NA, 0.611704587936401, 
0.19963726401329, 0.293040901422501, 0.182317450642586, 0.196896150708199
), Trust.2017 = c(0.0697203353047371, NA, 0.0602413564920425, 
0.04328977689147, 0.0153171354904771, 0.107215754687786, 0.0710951760411263, 
0.089847519993782, 0.0956650152802467), Dystopia.Residual.2017 = c(1.61448240280151, 
1.89217257499695, 2.22495865821838, 1.74922156333923, 1.42947697639465, 
1.31890726089478, 2.66845989227295, 1.68706583976746, 1.83722925186157
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

**Structure of dataframe**

```
   Country                          Region Happiness.Rank.2015 Happiness.Score.2015
1                 Angola              Sub-Saharan Africa                 137                4.033
2 Bosnia and Herzegovina      Central and Eastern Europe                  96                4.949
3       Congo (Kinshasa)              Sub-Saharan Africa                 120                4.517
4                 Greece                  Western Europe                 102                4.857
5              Indonesia               Southeastern Asia                  74                5.399
6                   Iraq Middle East and Northern Africa                 112                4.677
7           Sierra Leone              Sub-Saharan Africa                 123                4.507
8                  Sudan              Sub-Saharan Africa                 118                4.550
9                   Togo              Sub-Saharan Africa                 158                2.839
  Standard.Error.2015 Economy.2015 Family.2015 Health.2015 Freedom.2015 Trust.2015 Generosity.2015
1             0.04758      0.75778     0.86040     0.16683      0.10384    0.07122         0.12344
2             0.06913      0.83223     0.91916     0.79081      0.09245    0.00227         0.24808
3             0.03680           NA     1.00120     0.09806      0.22605    0.07625         0.24834
4             0.05062      1.15406     0.92933     0.88213      0.07699    0.01397              NA
5             0.02596      0.82827     1.08708     0.63793      0.46611         NA         0.51535
6             0.05232      0.98549     0.81889     0.60237           NA    0.13788         0.17922
7             0.07068      0.33024     0.95571          NA      0.40840    0.08786         0.21488
8             0.06740      0.52107     1.01404     0.36878      0.10081    0.14660         0.19062
9             0.06727      0.20868     0.13995     0.28443      0.36453    0.10731         0.16681
  Dystopia.Residual.2015                     Region.2016 Happiness.Rank.2016 Happiness.Score.2016
1                1.94939              Sub-Saharan Africa                 141                3.866
2                2.06367      Central and Eastern Europe                  87                5.163
3                2.86712              Sub-Saharan Africa                 125                4.272
4                1.80101                  Western Europe                  99                5.033
5                1.86399               Southeastern Asia                  79                5.314
6                1.95335 Middle East and Northern Africa                 112                4.575
7                2.51009              Sub-Saharan Africa                 111                4.635
8                2.20857              Sub-Saharan Africa                 133                4.139
9                1.56726              Sub-Saharan Africa                 155                3.303
  Lower.CI.2016 Upper.CI.2016 Economy.2016 Family.2016 Health.2016 Freedom.2016 Trust.2016
1         3.753         3.979      0.84731     0.66366     0.04991      0.00589    0.08434
2         5.063         5.263      0.93383     0.64367     0.70766      0.09511         NA
3         4.191         4.353      0.05661     0.80676     0.18800      0.15602    0.06075
4         4.935         5.131      1.24886     0.75473     0.80029      0.05822    0.04127
5         5.237         5.391      0.95104     0.87625     0.49374      0.39237    0.00322
6         4.446         4.704      1.07474     0.59205     0.51076      0.24856    0.13636
7         4.505         4.765      0.36485     0.62800          NA      0.30685    0.08196
8         3.928         4.350      0.63069     0.81928     0.29759           NA    0.10039
9         3.192         3.414      0.28123          NA     0.24811      0.34678    0.11587
  Generosity.2016 Dystopia.Residual.2016 Happiness.Rank.2017 Happiness.Score.2017 Whisker.high.2017
1         0.12071                2.09459                 140                3.795          3.951642
2         0.29889                2.48406                  90                5.182          5.276336
3         0.25458                2.74924                 126                4.280          4.357811
4              NA                2.12944                  87                5.227          5.325246
5         0.56521                2.03171                  81                5.262          5.352889
6         0.19589                1.81657                 117                4.497          4.622591
7         0.23897                3.01402                 106                4.709          4.850643
8         0.18077                2.10995                 130                4.139          4.345747
9         0.17517                2.13540                 150                3.495          3.594038
  whisker.low.2017 Economy.2017 Family.2017 Health.2017 Freedom.2017 Generosity.2017 Trust.2017
1         3.638358   0.85842818   1.1044120 0.049868666           NA      0.09792649 0.06972034
2         5.087665   0.98240942   1.0693359 0.705186307   0.20440318      0.32886750         NA
3         4.202190   0.09210235   1.2290235 0.191407025   0.23596135      0.24645583 0.06024136
4         5.128754   1.28948748   1.2394146 0.810198903   0.09573125              NA 0.04328978
5         5.171112   0.99553859   1.2744447 0.492345721   0.44332346      0.61170459 0.01531714
6         4.371409   1.10271049   0.9786132 0.501180470   0.28855553      0.19963726 0.10721575
7         4.567357   0.36842093   0.9841360 0.005564754   0.31869769      0.29304090 0.07109518
8         3.932253   0.65951669   1.2140086 0.290920824   0.01499586      0.18231745 0.08984752
9         3.395962   0.30544472   0.4318825 0.247105569   0.38042614      0.19689615 0.09566502
  Dystopia.Residual.2017
1               1.614482
2               1.892173
3               2.224959
4               1.749222
5               1.429477
6               1.318907
7               2.668460
8               1.687066
9               1.837229
```

**Update#1: What I have tried**

I have tried `apply` function using the code suggested by @RAB. It gave me warning message as below

**Code used**

```
dt <- apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm=T)
```

**Warning Message**

> 1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
>             argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

**str of dataframe**

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ Country               : chr  "Angola" "Bosnia and Herzegovina" "Congo (Kinshasa)" "Greece" ...
 $ Region                : chr  "Sub-Saharan Africa" "Central and Eastern Europe" "Sub-Saharan Africa" "Western Europe" ...
 $ Happiness.Rank.2015   : int  137 96 120 102 74 112 123 118 158
 $ Happiness.Score.2015  : num  4.03 4.95 4.52 4.86 5.4 ...
 $ Standard.Error.2015   : num  0.0476 0.0691 0.0368 0.0506 0.026 ...
 $ Economy.2015          : num  0.758 0.832 NA 1.154 0.828 ...
 $ Family.2015           : num  0.86 0.919 1.001 0.929 1.087 ...
 $ Health.2015           : num  0.1668 0.7908 0.0981 0.8821 0.6379 ...
 $ Freedom.2015          : num  0.1038 0.0925 0.2261 0.077 0.4661 ...
 $ Trust.2015            : num  0.07122 0.00227 0.07625 0.01397 NA ...
 $ Generosity.2015       : num  0.123 0.248 0.248 NA 0.515 ...
 $ Dystopia.Residual.2015: num  1.95 2.06 2.87 1.8 1.86 ...
 $ Region.2016           : chr  "Sub-Saharan Africa" "Central and Eastern Europe" "Sub-Saharan Africa" "Western Europe" ...
 $ Happiness.Rank.2016   : int  141 87 125 99 79 112 111 133 155
 $ Happiness.Score.2016  : num  3.87 5.16 4.27 5.03 5.31 ...
 $ Lower.CI.2016         : num  3.75 5.06 4.19 4.93 5.24 ...
 $ Upper.CI.2016         : num  3.98 5.26 4.35 5.13 5.39 ...
 $ Economy.2016          : num  0.8473 0.9338 0.0566 1.2489 0.951 ...
 $ Family.2016           : num  0.664 0.644 0.807 0.755 0.876 ...
 $ Health.2016           : num  0.0499 0.7077 0.188 0.8003 0.4937 ...
 $ Freedom.2016          : num  0.00589 0.09511 0.15602 0.05822 0.39237 ...
 $ Trust.2016            : num  0.08434 NA 0.06075 0.04127 0.00322 ...
 $ Generosity.2016       : num  0.121 0.299 0.255 NA 0.565 ...
 $ Dystopia.Residual.2016: num  2.09 2.48 2.75 2.13 2.03 ...
 $ Happiness.Rank.2017   : int  140 90 126 87 81 117 106 130 150
 $ Happiness.Score.2017  : num  3.8 5.18 4.28 5.23 5.26 ...
 $ Whisker.high.2017     : num  3.95 5.28 4.36 5.33 5.35 ...
 $ whisker.low.2017      : num  3.64 5.09 4.2 5.13 5.17 ...
 $ Economy.2017          : num  0.8584 0.9824 0.0921 1.2895 0.9955 ...
 $ Family.2017           : num  1.1 1.07 1.23 1.24 1.27 ...
 $ Health.2017           : num  0.0499 0.7052 0.1914 0.8102 0.4923 ...
 $ Freedom.2017          : num  NA 0.2044 0.236 0.0957 0.4433 ...
 $ Generosity.2017       : num  0.0979 0.3289 0.2465 NA 0.6117 ...
 $ Trust.2017            : num  0.0697 NA 0.0602 0.0433 0.0153 ...
 $ Dystopia.Residual.2017: num  1.61 1.89 2.22 1.75 1.43 ...
```

**Note:** I am new to R, please provide an explanation along with the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried apply function as suggested by @RAB. Unfortunately, it gave me an error saying "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" for all 9 Obs

Comment: Add what you tried in your original post with that error message. We want to help you learn, and the best way is by sharing what you have tried yourself! :)

Comment: what class is each column? You can use `str(data)` to see the class. They need to be numeric to get them mean, which you can get by using `as.numeric` (unless they are factors in which case use `as.numeric(as.character(<colname>))` )

Comment: @RAB..all columns are numeric..Please see updated question with "str of dataframe" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to be numeric for this to work, so step 1 will be to filter out only the numeric data (we will put the other stuff back in later)

You will need to replace "yourdata" with your dataframe name

Step 1: filter for only numeric

```
df <- Filter(is.numeric, yourdata)
```

Step 2: get the means

```
mns <- apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm=T) # this gets the mean of each row
```

Step 3: find the indexes of the NA values

```
nas <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(df), arr.ind = T)) 
# the data frame makes it easier to extract the row info for later
```

Step 4: substitute the NA values with the corresponding mean

```
df[which(is.na(df), arr.ind = T)] <- mns[nas$row]
```

Step 5: combine the non-numeric columns with the new columns

```
new_df <- cbind(Filter(Negate(is.numeric), yourdata), df)
```

**Edit:**

I was bored, so hear's a function for you:

```
replace_missing <- function(df, groups){

  cols <- names(df)

  df_char <- Filter(Negate(is.numeric), df)
  df_num  <- Filter(is.numeric, df)

  for(gg in 1:length(groups)){
    tmp <- df_num[, grep(groups[gg], names(df_num))]
    mns <- apply(tmp, 1, mean, na.rm=T)
    nas <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(tmp), arr.ind = T))
    if (nrow(nas) > 0){
      tmp[which(is.na(tmp), arr.ind = T)] <- mns[nas$row]
    }
    df_char <- cbind(df_char, tmp)
  }

  new_df <- cbind(df_char, df[, setdiff(names(df), names(df_char))])
  new_df <- new_df[, cols]
}

new_data <- replace_missing(yourdata, groups = c("Happiness.Rank", "Happiness.Score", 
                            "Family", "Economy"))
```

You can add as many as you want to the `groups` field

Comment: I am stuck at STEP4. Error is object 'means' not found. Does it have to be mean ?

Comment: sorry, mns. edited now. also, you can use this method on each subset of data (eg all data where the colname starts with 'Freedom` ect

Comment: @RAB..How would I approach that ? What it be possible for you to provide the example ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: editted with an example for freedom. after that you can probably work out the rest

Comment: editted with a function I wrote. Just include the list of variable names you want to look for missing in in the `groups` option

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly straight-foward `tidyverse` solution; the key here is to reshape data from wide to long, then "suitably" replace `NA` values before transforming data back to wide. I give (some) explanations at the end but I encourage you to execute the code line-by-line to understand what every step does.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.new <- df %>%
    gather(key, val, -Country, -Region, -Region.2016) %>%
    separate(key, c("what", "when"), sep = "\\.(?=\\d)", remove = FALSE) %>%
    group_by(Country, what) %>%
    mutate(val = replace(val, is.na(val), mean(val, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-what, -when) %>%
    spread(key, val)
df.new
## A tibble: 9 x 35
#  Country Region Region.2016 Dystopia.Residu… Dystopia.Residu… Dystopia.Residu…
#  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>                  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#1 Angola  Sub-S… Sub-Sahara…             1.95             2.09             1.61
#2 Bosnia… Centr… Central an…             2.06             2.48             1.89
#3 Congo … Sub-S… Sub-Sahara…             2.87             2.75             2.22
#4 Greece  Weste… Western Eu…             1.80             2.13             1.75
#5 Indone… South… Southeaste…             1.86             2.03             1.43
#6 Iraq    Middl… Middle Eas…             1.95             1.82             1.32
#7 Sierra… Sub-S… Sub-Sahara…             2.51             3.01             2.67
#8 Sudan   Sub-S… Sub-Sahara…             2.21             2.11             1.69
#9 Togo    Sub-S… Sub-Sahara…             1.57             2.14             1.84
## ... with 29 more variables: Economy.2015 <dbl>, Economy.2016 <dbl>,
##   Economy.2017 <dbl>, Family.2015 <dbl>, Family.2016 <dbl>,
##   Family.2017 <dbl>, Freedom.2015 <dbl>, Freedom.2016 <dbl>,
##   Freedom.2017 <dbl>, Generosity.2015 <dbl>, Generosity.2016 <dbl>,
##   Generosity.2017 <dbl>, Happiness.Rank.2015 <dbl>,
##   Happiness.Rank.2016 <dbl>, Happiness.Rank.2017 <dbl>,
##   Happiness.Score.2015 <dbl>, Happiness.Score.2016 <dbl>,
##   Happiness.Score.2017 <dbl>, Health.2015 <dbl>, Health.2016 <dbl>,
##   Health.2017 <dbl>, Lower.CI.2016 <dbl>, Standard.Error.2015 <dbl>,
##   Trust.2015 <dbl>, Trust.2016 <dbl>, Trust.2017 <dbl>, Upper.CI.2016 <dbl>,
##   Whisker.high.2017 <dbl>, whisker.low.2017 <dbl>
```

Explanation:

1. Reshape data from wide to long; keep columns `Country`, `Region` and `Region.2016` as they are. All other column names are given in new column `key` with values in `val`.
2. Separate all `key` entries such as `"Happiness.Score.2016"` into `"Happiness.Score" (column`what`) and`"2016"`(column`when`).
3. Group entries by `Country` and `what`.
4. We can now replace `NA`s per `Country` and `what` by the mean value across all years.
5. Lastly, `ungroup` and remove the `what` and `when` columns before
6. reshaping data from long to wide again to be consistent with original data format.

Mind you, it might actually be a lot easier (and more in line with "tidy" data) to keep your data in long format; but that's just my opinion.

---

Let's check for `Country == "Congo"`

```
df.new %>% filter(str_detect(Country, "Congo")) %>% select(contains("Economy"))
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#  Economy.2015 Economy.2016 Economy.2017
#         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1       0.0744       0.0566       0.0921
```

and compare with the original data

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(Country, "Congo")) %>% select(contains("Economy"))
#  Economy.2015 Economy.2016 Economy.2017
#1           NA      0.05661   0.09210235
```

So here `0.0744 = 1/2 * (0.05661 + 0.09210235)`.